# Are there any method to know weather photo was captured from front camera or back camera of android device

Tags: android, camera

Here i want to find camera id of currently open camera So that i can know weather image was captured from front or back camera. Are there any way to find it??

Comment: Are you running the camera in your app or are you using the native one?

Comment: I am using native one. are there any method? @zgc7009

Comment: You know what, I just looked through the Camera documentation and it doesn't appear there is anything to determine the currently open id... even if it is your own app! Super weird if you ask me and something that they might want to look in to, but unfortunately as of now I don't believe it is possible to get the id of the currently running camera regardless of which app it is active in.